# Intervention Image rounded corners upload

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I'm trying to upload my files as circles, but I can't make it work.
I've seen some topics about applying a mask to the image, but when I apply the mask it takes way to long and the server shuts the request down.

I'm using the `Intervention Image` library for Laravel

My code is as follows:

```
$identifier = "{$this->loggedUser->id}" . str_random(9) . ".{$file->getClientOriginalExtension()}";
$mask = $this->createCircleMask(200, 200);
$thumbMask = $this->createCircleMask(40, 40);
Image::make($file->getRealPath())->mask($mask)->save(public_path("images/profile/{$identifier}"));
Image::make($file->getRealPath())->mask($thumbMask)->save(public_path("images/profile/thumbs/{$identifier}"));
```

The `createCircleMask` method looks like this:

```
public function createCircleMask($width, $height)
{
    $circle = Image::canvas($width, $height, '#000000');
    return $circle->circle($width - 1, $width / 2, $height / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Here is a function that works in my case. But **ONLY** if I use the imagick driver. The standard gd library is very very slow, at least on my test computer.
You can have a look at vendor\intervention\image\src\Intervention\Image\Gd\Commands\MaskCommand.php to find out why.

```
public function upload() {

    $path = storage_path('app')."/";

    $image = \Image::make(\Input::file('image'));
    $image->encode('png');

    /* if you want to have a perfect and complete circle using the whole width and height the image
     must be shaped as as square. If your images are not guaranteed to be a square maybe you could
     use Intervention's fit() function */
    //  $image->fit(300,300);

    // create empty canvas
    $width = $image->getWidth();
    $height = $image->getHeight();
    $mask = \Image::canvas($width, $height);

    // draw a white circle
    $mask->circle($width, $width/2, $height/2, function ($draw) {
        $draw->background('#fff');
    });

    $image->mask($mask, false);
    $image->save($path."circled.png");

}
```